# What's the best way to validate RadioButtonLists that are built dynamically in a repeater?

Tags: c#, jquery, validation

I have a repeater that contains a RadioButtonList in each row.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptAccessories" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptAccessories_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="display: none">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAccID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <%-- POPULATE CONDITION TABLE--%>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblCondition" Width="640px" CssClass="rblist" ValidationGroup ="vag" Style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: -40px;" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

But I'm really struggling to find a way to validate the radio buttons have a selected value.

I have tried using a RequiredFieldValidator, but this errors saying that it can't find the controls.

I've also tried using JQuery, but again this is challenging as I don't know how to pass JQuery the id of the RadioButtonList as it is only created at runtime:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
    var cnt = $("#rblCondition :radio:checked").length;
    if (cnt == 0) 
    {
        alert('Select any option.');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
        else 
            alert('Well Done!!!!');
    });
});​
```

I also tried setting a custom CSS class up and using this as the identifier:

```
var cnt = $(".required :radio:checked").length;
```

But this didn't work.

I've a feeling I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: The abbreviation `cnt` makes me say bad things in my head.. Ha... also `ValidationGroup ="vag"`

Comment: It's a naming strategy I've worked hard to perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be someplace else as `RequiredFieldValidator` should work on your scenario as long as you put it within `ItemTemplate`

```
<td colspan="6">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblCondition" Width="640px" 
        CssClass="rblist" 
        ValidationGroup ="vag" 
        Style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: -40px;" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
        ControlToValidate="rblCondition"
        ErrorMessage="required"
        ValidationGroup ="vag" 
        runat="server"/>        
</td>
```

Comment: I get the error: "Unable to find control id 'rblCondition' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of 'RequiredFieldValidator1'." using this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the jQuery route.. The rendered ID will start with the ID you give it, followed by an underscore, followed by information asp.net gives it to keep track of it. You can view the source of the page to see what html is actually rendered.

So you should be able to use the jQuery [Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('div[id^="rblCondition_"]').each(function() {
    //validate each radio button list
});
```

Note that I'm not positive asp.net renders the container as a div. Also, for efficiency, it might be good to filter the result set using a quicker selector before using starts with.